# Returning lists from url in Django

Tags: django, django-views, django-urls

Is there a way how to return lists that are passed in to url as parameters? I've noticed that if a list is passed to a view url then when you access the said passed list in the view via `self.kwargs['parameter']` and print it then the result will be `['item', 'item2']` which looks like a `list`, however the `type(self.kwargs['parameter'])` will actually be of `<'str'>` not a `<'list'>`.

The example url that has a list passed looks something like this:

[http://127.0.0.1:8000/%5B'list_item',%20'another_list_item'%5D/%5B'list_item1',%20'another_list_item1'%5D/](http://127.0.0.1:8000/%5B%27list_item%27,%20%27another_list_item%27%5D/%5B%27list_item1%27,%20%27another_list_item1%27%5D/)

Am I correct in stating that `self.kwargs['parameter']` only takes the raw string of the url and does not know what type of data was passed?

EDIT

Im using only python. Not using ajax

Comment: I think self.request.GET should have a QueryDict that you can retrieve the list from using self.request.GET.get_list('parameter')

Comment: That is not the correct way of passing list. If you have to pass list to django pass it as data attribute of ajax and get it like this `request.GET.getlist('your_key[]')`

Comment: For some purposes you might encode a short list with your own choice of delimiter. If `kwargs['list']` is `"foo_bar_baz"` you can easily get a list as `kwargs['list'].split('_')`